# Aborting jenkin builds does not kill surefire sub-process for Maven project type

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-surefire-plugin

I aborted Jenkins job(Maven build) manually but the surefire-maven plugin (java process) was still active and running until I manually killed java process.

goals & options: clean test -Dxxxx
Maven Plugin using :

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I tried running the maven build test locally. Terminated with CTRL+C , Observed that the app was still running. and surefire was accessed and NOT terminated.

The only maven plugin I am using:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment>uat</environment>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>tag</name>
                        <value>login</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Expecting that Maven should be terminated properly when the jenkins job is ABORTED. To avoid below errors:
1. App should be stopped when jenkins job is aborted
2. if we run the jenkin job again, it throws an error "Permission denied to access report.js"
3. surefire reports are still active after Aborting the jenkins job.